# Parsing url parameters in a String

Tags: actionscript-3, loadvars

I am using the example code in flash. I want a single variable and not the whole text.
I have a dynamic textfield called `OUTPUT` on the stage.

```
var fl_TextLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var fl_TextURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.testing.com/Christmas.txt");

fl_TextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fl_CompleteHandler);

function fl_CompleteHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var textData:String = new String(fl_TextLoader.data);
    OUTPUT.text = textData;
}

fl_TextLoader.load(fl_TextURLRequest);
```

The Christmas text file contents:

```
Var1=Jesus&Var2=Mary&Var3=Christmas
```

The `OUTPUT` comes out with the whole string. How do I get the url parameter values separately?

Like `OUTPUT.text = textData.Var1;` (<--- But this does not work.)

Answer (score 1):

The .data property is just a string, the raw data returned by the HTTP call, so you will have to parse the variable-value pairs, either using simple .split() on the strings or using the URLVariables object, that can do the parsing for you:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLVariables.html#decode()

Comment: This guy is right, do this: `var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(fl_TextLoader.data); 
trace(vars.Var2); //Traces "Mary"`